# Google model viewer lighting

Tags: 3d, mobile-safari, web-component, arquicklook

We have created a model for use with the google model viewer web component [here](https://download.intermarketing.com/kawai/).

Lighting on the model is as expected when opened in AR (IOS - Safari), but not in the viewer. I would like to understand why.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an `environment-image` attribute to your modelviewer with a plain white image or something similar.

Unless your models are flat/unlit you will need the `environment-image` as far as I understand.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in model-viewer that some objects are just black. This is an open issue as you can see on the [model-viewer GitHub](https://github.com/google/model-viewer/issues/1060). You can try recreating this model or creating another model, many times it works.